# Toggle bootstrap value

Tags: toggle, bootstrap-4

How to find toggle value when using toggle in bootstrap.

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
        //Enabled means it will enter into if loop, here we sort machine list by green
        if('toggle is Enable'){
           //do something
        }
        //if toggle is disable
       else{
            //do something
        }
    })
  });
```

In the above example, when i toggle to Enable or Disable, how to find the value of toggle checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean that?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/MAXXALANDER/nrh6pq2n/1/

```
// HTML
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-event" checked>
<div id="console-event"> </div>

// Jquery
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {

        if($(this).is(":checked")){
           //do something
           $('#console-event').html('on');
        } else{
           $('#console-event').html('off');        
        } 

    }) 
  });
```

Comment: This works for check box, but not for toggle button as [link(http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

value of toggle checkbox ? means you mean whether checkbox is checked or not,
then here is the solution

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

Comment: I do not mean, whether the checkbox is selected or not. 
For example, when toggle is representing "Enable" mode and i am changing it to "Disable" mode, in this case, i need to call a function in javascript according to "Enable" or "disable" condition

Comment: toggle will be enabled when checkbox is checked and disabled when it is unchecked right

Comment: Yes, but it is not checkbox, it is a toggel button like [link](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/), problem is am always getting tru, even i switch from enable to disable or diable to enable when using 
accept
value of toggle checkbox ? means you mean whether checkbox is checked or not, then here is the solution

$(this).is(":checked")